# Поиск в коллекции по двум полям со сложностью O(log(n))

Tags: java, коллекции, поиск

Всех приветствую, хотел бы узнать по поводу алгоритма со сложностью O(log(n)).

Есть класс, в нём атрибуты `login`, `name`, `age`, `pass` и т. д. Коллекция для них может быть любой, но желательно хотелось бы увидеть реализацию на TreeSet и т. д.

Как найти экземпляр класса в коллекции по атрибутам `login` и `name`? Коллекция может содержать от 5 000 до 50 000 объектов.

Comment: Сделайте HashMap<String, Person>, где ключи, например, login + name,  а значения — ваши объекты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cоздайте составной ключ `PersonKey`, в котором будут содержаться `login` и `name`. Будем использовать `TreeMap`, поэтому реализуйте интерфейс `Comparable`:

```java
public class PersonKey implements Comparable<PersonKey> {

    private final String login;
    private final String name;

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PersonKey other) {
        return Comparator.comparing(PersonKey::getLogin)
                .thenComparing(PersonKey::getName)
                .compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

Теперь можно складывать объекты в `TreeMap`:

```java
Map<PersonKey, Person> people = new TreeMap<>();
people.put(new PersonKey(login, name), new Person(login, name, age))
```

И доставать за `O(log(n))`:

```java
people.get(new PersonKey(login, name));
```

Comment: Вот интересно, а если бы через HashMap реализовать, по сложности бы также O(log(n)) было? Если не ошибаюсь, то с 8 версии джавы там под капотом красно-чёрные деревья для каждого бакета, а это значит что при хорошей хэш-функции может даже быстрее получится?

Comment: Из HashMap, в среднем, вытащить элемент [быстрее](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjxf5.png), так как `O(1)`.

Comment: Вот я и думаю, странно что в задании требуется именно за log(n), когда можно было бы быстрее)

Comment: Поэтому на практике обычно используют HashMap. А TreeMap только для ответов на вопросы :D

Comment: @Vadik а можно попросить показать реализацию на HashMap?

Comment: C `HashMap` все точно так же, только не нужно реализовывать `implements Comparable`, а достаточно в классе `PersonKey` переопределить методы `equals` и `hashCode`.

Comment: Об `equals` и `hashCode` написано в любой книге по Java. Эти методы за вас может сгенерировать IDE. Текущий ответ редактировать не буду, так как он тогда не будет отвечать на поставленный вопрос. Если не справитесь, то заводите новый вопрос с указанием того, что конкретно у вас не поулчилось сделать.